# Get list of packages that provide (APT)

Tags: apt

How can I generate a list of packages that the specific package provides using the apt-family?

Comment: I don't really get your question. Do you want the list of files from a package, a list of dependencies or a list of packages depending on this package?

Comment: Can you please try and clean up your question? It's unclear to everyone here exactly what you're trying to do. Are you trying to get a list of executables and/or programs that are included in a given package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`apt-cache show`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=apt-cache) to display information about available packages, or [`dpkg -s`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dpkg) to display information about installed packages.

```
apt-cache show PACKAGE-NAME | awk '$1 == "Provides:" {print $2}'
dpkg -s INSTALLED-PACKAGE-NAME | awk '$1 == "Provides:" {print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
LANG=C aptitude show gnome-terminal|grep ^Provides
```